# Pre tag does not render correctly in blogger

Tags: html

The following code is the html content of a web page:
[image]
This is correctly rendered as shown:
[image]
However the same html in a blogger post shows an empty page.
The other interesting thing is, the first time you enter the html in the HTML page, the characters remain as pasted, but once the page is refreshed, the escape characters are rendered in the HTML  pane as shown in the next image but the compose pane is empty.
[image]

It looks like some quirk of the blogger. Browser does not seem to matter (Edge or FireFox latest),

The extra 'pre' tags are added by the blogger. What I pasted is what was shown on my page submitted to IIS. I feel that the file processing by blogger is the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: You have an extra closing of `pre` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `</pre>`'s in your html. Your browser tries to autocorrect it, and this often goes wrong. (This is why valid html is important!)

If you use any decent IDE like Visual Studio, Sublime (free), PHPstorm, Netbeans(free), or even dreamweaver, or notepad++(free) with some plugins, all of these programs would have notified you on this particular issue, so I can definitely recommend using one.

Answer (score 0):

The blogger somehow reformatted the entered text in the html which is the reason that Pre tags got duplicated. Also I might have had some browser problems. I went back and added sufficient space after the pre and before the /pre and now it seems it is rendering correctly.